# Comparison of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, convexity, convex-analysis

Given a function $f$  from $R^2$ to $R$ satisfying tha following:

$1)$ $f$ is a **convex** function which **vanishes** on $(0,1)$ and on $(1,0).$

$2)$  $f$ is a decreasing function on $x$ and on $y$ and $f$ is negative if $x,y > 1$ and $f$ is positive if $x$ and $y$ are $ < 1.$

Let $g(x,y)=1-x-y,$ where $(x,y) \in R^2.$
Which of these functions is less than the other $f(x,y)\leq g(x,y)$ or $f(x,y)\geq g(x,y)$ for $x,y$ in $]-\infty,0],$ $[0,1]$ and $[1+\infty[.$

Many thanks.

Comment: What is a decreasing function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: The assumptions are not completely clear to me; however note that for any $\lambda>0$ the function $\lambda f$ still satisfies the assumptions (I assume that $\lambda f$ is still "decreasing", whatever it means). This means that, based on the assumptions only, $f\le g$ can't be ensured in the half-plane {g<0}, and $f\ge g$ can't be ensured in the half-plane {g>0}.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov this means $f$ is decreasing on $x$ and on $y$

Comment: @PietroMajer thank you for your reply! I edited the assumptions.

Comment: Then in general the only set where there is a certain inequality is the segment with endpoints $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, where $f(x,y)\le0=g(x,y)$. For  any other point $(x,y)$, you can have both $f(x,y)<g(x,y)$ or  $f(x,y)>g(x,y)$ (e.g. take $f=2g$ or $f=g/2$)